# Does android keystore and “Clear data” of the “Settings” app are related?

Tags: applications, security, encryption, system-apps

I am working on a system app where i am storing some sensitive data in EncryptedSharedPreference.
I realise that my app is not working as expected if I do clear data of android Settings app. That is happening because my sensitive data stored in encrypted shared preference was changing.
When I observe the encrypted_myapp_pref.xml file, I observe that encrypted value of those sensitive data is not changing. but value of key material was changing (**androidx_security_crypto_encrypted_prefs_key_keyset** and **androidx_security_crypto_encrypted_prefs_value_keyset**). Hence while decrypted my sensitive data, it gave me wrong value and that was affecting on app. When I tried the same logic with priv app or user app (without using sharedUserId="android.uid.system" it is working as expected.

So the problem is, if I am using system app with shared user id and clearing the data of settings app, on device reboot, key material of my own app changes and Encrypted shared preference will not give proper values back.

Comment: Interesting question but I'm afraid it's more development oriented, so off-topic here.

Comment: I thought stackexchange deals with android development related issues as well. Will wait for some time, else will remove the question from here. Thank you @IrfanLatif

Comment: usually only the keys got deleted, not actually data itself. this is android internals, might be a bug or it is intended, who knows? can't you instruct TEE to flush everything each time your app is running initial setup?

Comment: thanks for the reply. We confirm that it is android system bug. Actully it clears android key store. My app creates new instance of keys and hence I could see change in cryptographic keys

Comment: Should I delete this question from here?